# Django Rest Framework 3.1.1 setting status success and failure based on validation errors

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am new in django framework. Please help me,How to add extra status parameter in rest framework to show the success and failure of response based on validation. I have tried with to_indernal_value function but I dont know hot set status parameter in response.
My serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Abstract User Model Serilization
    """
    customer=CustomerSerializer()
    client_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    client_secret = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username', 'password','email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'customer', 'client_id', 'client_secret')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        depth=2
    def get_client_id(self, obj):
        user_id=User.objects.filter(username=obj).first()
        client=Application.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).first()
        if client is not None:
            return client.client_id
        else:
            return ""

    def get_client_secret(self, obj):
        user_id=User.objects.filter(username=obj).first()
        client=Application.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).first()
        if client is not None:
            return client.client_secret
        else:
            return ""

    def create(self, validated_data):

        profile_data = validated_data.pop('customer')
        user=User(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'], first_name=validated_data['first_name'], last_name=validated_data['last_name'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        # user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        users_group = Group.objects.get(name='Customers')
        user.groups = [users_group]
        Application.objects.create(user=user, client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
                                   authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_PASSWORD)
        Customer.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('customer')
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.username =validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.password=make_password(validated_data.get('password', instance.password),salt=None,hasher='unsalted_md5')
        instance.save()
        #Customer.objects.update(user=instance, **profile_data)
        Customer.objects.filter(user=instance).values().update(**profile_data)
        return instance
```

I am using generic views

```
class CustomerCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Only POST method is allowed without Authentication Token
    """
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)
```

Expected Response on validation

```
{
    "Status":0
    "username": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "customer": {
        "email_id": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ],
        "latitude": [
            "A valid number is required."
        ],
        "mobile_no": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ],
        "longitude": [
            "A valid number is required."
        ]
    },
    "password": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}

On success status set as success
{
   status:1
   created record details
}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding a fundamental tenant of [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  That kind of status field is captured in the HTTP response _header_.  Namely the [status code field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of the response header.  e.g. [200 for "OK", 201 for "Created", 400 for "Bad Request", et c.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Yes, that I know but I have to set externally this status because its a requirement from mobile app developer. They are not ready to read HTTP status code. Based response status they will decide is their any error or success not from HTTP status code.

Comment: What stack and library are they using to access the REST API?  You might be better off giving them a code snippet that shows them how to read HTTP response headers.   Anyways.  Good luck!

Comment: They are using Android and IOS based library to GET and POST response.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment by Ross Rogers. It's better to use the HTTP status code.

if you have to do that, you may override the exception_handler.

my_view_utils.py

```
def exception_handler(exc):
    """
        fork from rest_framework.views.exception_handler
    """
    ERROR_INDICATOR = 'status';

    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.APIException):
        headers = {}
        if getattr(exc, 'auth_header', None):
            headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = exc.auth_header
        if getattr(exc, 'wait', None):
            headers['Retry-After'] = '%d' % exc.wait

        if isinstance(exc, exceptions.ValidationError):
            exc.status_code = 422  # 422 Unprocessable Entity
            data = {ERROR_INDICATOR: 422, 'error_detail': exc.detail}
        else:
            data = {
                ERROR_INDICATOR: getattr(exc, 'error_code', False) or exc.status_code,
                'error_detail': exc.detail
            }

        if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.NotAuthenticated,
                            exceptions.AuthenticationFailed)):
            # auth failed, response
            data.update({ERROR_INDICATOR: status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED})

        return Response(data, status=exc.status_code, headers=headers)

    elif isinstance(exc, Http404):
        data = {ERROR_INDICATOR: 404}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    elif isinstance(exc, PermissionDenied):
        data = {ERROR_INDICATOR: 403}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    # Note: Unhandled exceptions will raise a 500 error.
    return None
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_view_utils.exception_handler',
}
```